# Dynamically adding dictionary values based on row count from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am rewriting some code of mine and feel there must be a better more dynamic way to do the below. Currently as you can see I am creating a condition based directly on the row count and adding values from there. However I don't want to have to make static conditions for multiple values `if row_count == 3:` `if row_count == 4:` etc. I'm positive there must be a more efficient way to achieve this. Any pointers would be appreciated.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(main):
    filters = '*specificname*.csv'
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, filters):
        df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(root, filename),error_bad_lines=False)
        row_count = len(df.index)
        device_dic = collections.defaultdict()
        if row_count == 2:
            device_dic[df.iloc[0][1]]  = {}
            device_dic[df.iloc[0][1]]['item1'] = df.iloc[0][2]
            device_dic[df.iloc[0][1]]['item2'] = df.iloc[0][3]
            device_dic[df.iloc[1][1]] = {}
            device_dic[df.iloc[1][1]]['item1'] = df.iloc[1][2]
            device_dic[df.iloc[1][1]]['item2'] = df.iloc[1][3]
            for key in device_dic.iterkeys():
                device.append(key)
```

Comment: What about a dict with keys equal to the row counts you want to process and values equal to processing functions.  The multiple keys could map to the same processing function and you could easily add additional cases.

Comment: @PaulJoireman can you elaborate with an example please?

Answer (score 0):

```
def func1(device_dict):

    device_dic[df.iloc[0][1]]  = {}
    device_dic[df.iloc[0][1]]['item1'] = df.iloc[0][2]
    device_dic[df.iloc[0][1]]['item2'] = df.iloc[0][3]
    device_dic[df.iloc[1][1]] = {}
    device_dic[df.iloc[1][1]]['item1'] = df.iloc[1][2]
    device_dic[df.iloc[1][1]]['item2'] = df.iloc[1][3]
    for key in device_dic.iterkeys():
        device.append(key)

    # Or whatever you want to return
    return device

def func2(device_dict):
    # your code here
    pass



# Store each function in a dict
process_map = {2 : func1, 3: func2, 4: func2, ...}


for root, dirs, files in os.walk(main):
   filters = '*specificname*.csv'
   for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, filters):
      df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(root, filename),error_bad_lines=False)
      row_count = len(df.index)
      device_dic = collections.defaultdict()

      # Could also use get() to provide a default processing func
      process_func = process_map[row_count]

      result = process_func(device_dict)
```

Comment: to be honest, I have no idea what your doing here

Comment: Essentially I'm using the ``process_map`` dict as an extensible conditional selector.   When the ``row_count`` is 2 you the code selects ``func1`` from the map to process the data.   For other row counts you insert that number as a key and define a new function for the value (i.e. ``func2``).

Comment: I'm assuming you want to do some sort of different processing for the different row counts, this just provides a way to encapsulate that processing in a separate function and quickly select what to do based on the value of ``row_count``

Comment: No I am just looking to take the data from the rows and add them to the dictionary. Each row has 3 columns. I want to add the `[0][1]` to be the first key. Next column im adding the items associated with the first key. Then the next key at `[1][1]` and its associated item and values `[1][2]` etc. `if row_count == 1` there is only ony key and its associated items and values etc

Comment: sorry but dont see how this is any better than what i was looking to avoid initially. I could just as well make `if row_count == 1` 2 3 4 5 6 etc. Unless im not understanding your answer correctly it just looks like your making new function for each possible row count result?

Comment: You're correct, the only minor advantage would be (a) to keep your walk function smaller by eliminating a potentially large if..elif..elif...else statement and (b) if similar processing is applied to multiple row counts you could encapsulate that common processing in a single function instead of duplicating it in each elif clause.    But these are minor advantages, maybe not worth it.